Entity Framework Core: restrict and sort on first record of 1:many related join
I have two related entities:

Registration w/ various fields such as UserName, etc.
RegistrationAction w/ fields: Registration Id, Action Taken

I have a page showing all Registration records with their most recent ActionTaken. I need to be able to filter the Registration records based on their most recent ActionTaken as well as be able to sort on various fields, including ActionTaken.
Here is my code for doing the restriction and sorting (pageIndex, pageSize, and prevPageSize are all pass through values that do paging on the Registration query):
private async Task LoadData(int? pageIndex, int? pageSize, int? prevPageSize, string? filter, string? state)
{
    var extraFilter = DecodeState(state);

    var query = DbContext.Registrations.AsQueryable();

    // Restrict the RegistrationActions to only the most current ActionTaken
    // (A) NEED to use this "Join" in the where clause (1) below, an order by (2) below.
    query = query.Include(x => x.RegistrationActions.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).Take(1));

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains(filter) || x.FirstName.Contains(filter) || (x.MiddleName != null
            && x.MiddleName.Contains(filter)) || x.LastName.Contains(filter) || x.Email.Contains(filter));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extraFilter) && Enum.TryParse(extraFilter, out RegistrationActionState actionState))
    {
        // Filter by the latest RegistrationAction.
        query = (1) Need to restrict the ENTIRE query by the above Take(1) joined RegistrationAction's ActionTaken.
    }

    if (SortField == nameof(Registration.FullName))
    {
        query = CurrentSortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ThenBy(x => x.FirstName).ThenBy(x => x.MiddleName) :
            query.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastName).ThenByDescending(x => x.FirstName).ThenByDescending(x => x.MiddleName);
    }
    else if (SortField == nameof(Registration.UserName))
    {
        query = CurrentSortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(x => x.UserName) : query.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserName);
    }
    else if (SortField == nameof(Registration.Email))
    {
        query = CurrentSortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending ? query.OrderBy(x => x.Email) : query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Email);
    }
    else if (SortField == nameof(RegistrationAction.ActionTaken))
    {
        query = CurrentSortOrder == -- (2) Need to order the ENTIRE query by the above Take(1) joined RegistrationAction's ActionTaken.
    }

    await OnGetAsync(query, pageIndex, pageSize, prevPageSize, filter);

    RegistrationViewModels = Entities.Select(UserRegistrationsPage.ConvertToViewModel).ToList();
}

The key points in the code above are (1) and (2) where:

(1) is the possible query restriction on the joined (A) record. I need to restrict all registrations by their joined record values from (A).
(2) is the possible query order by on the joined (A) record. I need to order all registrations by their joined record values from (A).

When filter (1) or order by (2) is applied, this is a sample resulting SQL that I need:
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[UserName], [t0].[Id], [t0].[ActionTaken], [t0].[RegistrationId]
FROM (
    SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[UserName]
    FROM [auth].[Registration] AS [r]
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t1].[Id], [t1].[ActionTaken], [t1].[CreatedDate], [t1].[RegistrationId]
    FROM (
        SELECT [r0].[Id], [r0].[ActionTaken], [r0].[CreatedDate], [r0].[RegistrationId], 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [r0].[RegistrationId] ORDER BY [r0].[CreatedDate] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [auth].[RegistrationAction] AS [r0]
    ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[RegistrationId]
-- Where [t0].[ActionTaken] = 'Approved' (1)
ORDER BY [t0].ActionTaken -- (2) 

Whenever I try and add the where clause on the .Include() like so:
query = query.Where(x => x.RegistrationActions.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate).First().ActionTaken == actionState);

It restricts the Join, which is not what I want.
The only options I have been able to find are add whole new joins like so (haven't gotten this code to work right either), that do the restriction:
query = query.Join(DbContext.RegistrationActions.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate)
    .Take(1)
    .Where(x => x.ActionTaken == actionState), r => r.Id, ra => ra.Registration.Id, (query1, query2) => query1);

I'm ok if the code gets ugly and I need to special case the query for instances (1), (2) and (1) AND (2).
Any help?

The condition Where [t0].[ActionTaken] = 'Approved' filters the entire query, which, as I see it, is also what happens with the first clause query = query.Where(x => .... Can you explain the difference, maybe by adding some sample data?
